# Salesforce Integration Resources

Tags: integration

I am new to Community. I just started my career in salesforce development. I am looking to learn about Integration in salesforce.what are the best resources to start for learning Integration. I am looking for practical approach rather than theoretical approach.

Any pointers can be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for some practical approach to learn Integrations, the best way i can suggest is Salesforce Trailhead.

[Salesforce Trailhead Integration](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/super_badges/superbadge_integration)

Try to complete the superbadge which covers almost all the topics related to salesforce integrations.